# WebClient, Zip, Isolated Storage in Windows 8 metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I have a fairly complex scenario that I try to port to Windows 8 from Windows Phone 7.

I need to

1. Download s Zip file from the internet
2. Unzip it to the isolated storage
3. Read the unzipped xml files and images

Problems

1. In Windows Phone 7 I use WebClient that is no longer available in Windows 8. I tried HttpClientHandler but I am only able to download the ZIP file as a string and I do no know how to save it to isolated storage.
2. I found ZipArchive class but it takes a IO.Stream and I am not really sure how to use it (if I had the file save somewehre - point 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just starting out with the new API's as well (so this might be off a bit), but based on the documentation:

- [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and it's default handler [`HttpClientHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) return a [`Task<HttpResponseMessage>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from [`SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- The [`HttpResponseMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a property, [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is of type [`HttpContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- [`HttpContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in turn has a method, [`ReadAsStreamAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns [`Task<Stream>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you should be able to use (albeit indirectly) to pass to [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Or** you can just use the [`HttpClient.GetStreamAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551738%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the stream (much simpler):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri);
```

<sub><strike>If that doesn't work then you could also just wrap the string you get now in a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and pass it to [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but that sounds kind of unsafe because of possible encoding problems.</strike></sub>

Comment: thanks, I never thought of such an easy solution. I had 20+ lines using background transfer and file save